# How to fix unhandled exception error

Tags: c#, exception, installshield

I wrote a small application and added an install shield project. After installing the application in C:\Program Files I can run it as administrator without any problem. But when I run it without admin privileges it gives me this error :

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>   Operation must use an undateable query

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that your install has an implied dependence on running as Administrator.  For example, users are generally allowed write access to "C:\Program Files", this prevents misbehaving programs from making unauthorized changes to your applications.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your applications tries to access some files in the `C:\Program Files` directory and to do that you have to have admin privileges. But it's hard to tell. You can try to debug your application and see if it throws the exception and debug mode. If it happens as well you can investigate it from there. other option is to add some exception handling (`try..catch` blocks) and logging all the thrown exceptions into a file. After running the application in non-admin mode you can check the file for details.

Comment: yes I compiled program in normally mode it work truly , even i did copy installed file in other folders instead of installed folder, It work truly in normal mode, but in installed folder it don't work

Comment: Then I'd try logging the exceptions and trying to investigate it from there. Unfortunately your question is very general and so it's difficult to point you out into a specific direction. I only can suggest the strategies mentioned above.

Comment: If your requirement is that limited users can run your app, then every file and registry entry you update must be in areas that limited users can update. The ProgramFiles folder (where people unfortunately often store their data files) is NOT one of those places - there is a folder location called Users Application Data folder for that, as the name implies, AppDataFolder or LocalAppDataFolder in the MSI world.  If your requirement is that you need to be an admin to run the app, give it an elevation manifest so it will ask for admin privilege in the usual way.